# Flowtype: Extend Array type parameter

Tags: javascript, flowtype

First of all, forgive me if my wording is incorrect, I'm not so familiar with all of the typing jargon.

I have two types: `A` and `B`, where `B` is an extension of `A`, like so:

```
type A = { a: string };
type B = { a: string, b: string };
```

Asserting that a value of type `B` conforms to type `A` works fine:

```
const bar: B = { a: 'hello', b: 'world' };
(bar: A); // No problemo
```

But when wrapping the value into an array, the assertion goes bad:

```
const bars: Array<B> = [bar]; // This is fine
(bars: Array<B>); // Also fine
(bars: Array<A>); // Breaks!!
```

Am I completely misunderstanding something? Is this a Generics problem, an Array problem, or just a bug in Flow?

Flow version: v0.52.0

Check it out yourself on [Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCCYAvGAN5gCGAXGAM4YBOAlgHYDmYAvgNya4CAIVIVqdRq04AaMACMJzdlz7oAxnDaN5VJnRFlKtMAHIAFnhjwTshaYRwmMACYme-DVow6m9OoSYmKiwAHiEAPlEAbTldAF1+VAAKWL0iAEp+FN0-IkDgsPDM5NTcgKDQwiLeIA)

Comment: what do you think about this?
type A = { a: string, b?: string };
type B = { a: string, b?: string };

Comment: @MarkoSavic I don't want to change type A to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the type parameter `T` in `Array<T>` is invariant-- meaning it does not accept supertypes or subtypes when considering a subtyping relationship. Check out the docs on variance here for more info on that: https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/variance/#toc-invariance

What you're looking for is a data structure with a covariant type parameter. Specifically, you may want to use `$ReadOnlyArray<T>` instead.

[Try it](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoALgTwA4FMwCCYAvGAN5gCGAXGAM7oBOAlgHYDmYAvgNwY74AQiXJVaDFhwA0YAEbimbTr1SoAxnFYM5lRrWGkKNMAHIAFrhjwTM+aYRxGMACYnufABSzdtAgEoeMGBgMAA5ODBsRjhZGFwAWzhVDS10HUY6WgASACVcSmcAeVYYTAJGRkpMAB5BAD4RAG1vRgBdQOCwABUzZjowPrAoNlxUL11MsFz8opKyiqrauoCgkIIYOgjh1lHxjOy8guLS8sqagmWOkIAxEbBWRDBqPyA)

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know about $ReadOnlyArray<T>, I think I'll only use that one from now on :D

Comment: No problem! ReadOnlyArray does not let you mutate it, though. It probably won't be useful in every situation.

Comment: I realize that, and I love immutability :p. There will be exceptions, but ReadOnlyArray will be my go-to from now on.